# Database Design Optimization

Tags: mysql, database-design

This one is sort of a homework question, in that it is related to a question I have for my introductory databases course but is not the question itself. I am studying out of Phillip Pratt's "A Guide to MySql" and am stuck on a problem in the second chapter.
The problem states:

> Indicate the changes (using the shorthand representation) that you
>   would need to make the current deign of the Premiere Products database
>   to support the following requirements. A Customer is not necessarily
>   represented by a single sales rep, but can be represented by several
>   sales reps. When a customer places an order, the sales rep who gets
>   the commission on the order must be in the collection of sales reps
>   who represent the customer.

The database is currently designed as below (note that the bold fields are the primary keys):

> Rep (**Rep_Num**, Last_Name, First_Name, Street, City, State, Zip, Commission, Rate)
>
> Customer (**Customer_Num**, Customer_Name, Street, City, State, Zip, Balance, Credit_Limit, Rep_Num)
>
> Orders (**Order_Num**, Order_Date, Customer_Num)
>
> Part(**Part_Num**, Description, On_Hand, Class, Warehouse, Price)
>
> Order_Line (**Order_Num**, **Part_Num**, Num_Ordered, Quoted_Price)

My solution to the problem was to add a separate table for representation as follows:

> Rep (**Rep_Num**, Last_Name, First_Name, Street, City, State, Zip, Commission, Rate)
>
> Customer (**Customer_Num**, Customer_Name, Street, City, State, Zip, Balance, Credit_Limit)
>
> Represents(**Represents_Id**, Customer_Num, Rep_Num)
>
> Orders (**Order_Num**, Order_Date, Represents_Id)
>
> Part (**Part_Num**, Description, On_Hand, Class, Warehouse, Price)
>
> Order_Line (**Order_Num**, **Part_Num**, Num_Ordered, Quoted_Price)

I am wondering if this is the most efficient way to handle the proposed problem, and if my solution has any obvious flaws?

Comment: This is not "Optimization"; it is asking how to model a new requirement given the current schema.

Comment: I agree the question itself is asking how to model, but that is not my question. I have implemented a model that works, I am simply wondering how optimal my model is.

Comment: Looks good to me. It's certainly the classic solution for the multiple reps probelm, and there's usually a good reason why solutions are the classic!

Comment: @James Bender: Your model looks good to me (I'd recommend consistency in naming though : either both `Represents_id` or `Represents_Num` in `Represents` and `Orders`). Not sure if that important in the context of your task, but in real world, `Represents` can have `date_from`/`date_through` attributes...

Comment: Thanks. I had a couple solutions in mind (one involving an array), but I wasn't sure which was the more "classic" solution to submit.

Comment: Without knowing the book you refer too, it's really hard to answer.  To me, it would be easiest and better to just add **Rep_Num** to your **Orders** table.  Also, your new **Orders** tables doesn't have **Customer_Num**.  But again, I don't know that book.

Comment: You don't care which customer places an order?

Comment: Common practice is naming thse many-to-many joining tables after the relationship - often, in the form of "table1-table2". So, instead of "represents", you might name it "customer-rep". To an outsider, the difference between "rep" and "represents" might not be obvious....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of the question seems to be to introduce multi-column primary keys, and the fact that a foreign key needs a unique key to reference (in this case `Orders (Rep_Num, Customer_num) references Represents (Rep_Num, Customer_num)`):

> Represents(**Rep_Num, Customer_Num**)
>
> Orders (**Order_Num**, Order_Date, *Rep_Num, Customer_Num*)

You could admittedly maintain a `Represents_Id` and reference that instead in `Orders`.

Your solution's flaw is that `Orders (Represents_Num)` doesn't necessarily reference a valid representative for that specific customer.

---

On a completely off-topic note, your solution is actually the correct one in practice: the sales who picks up the phone gets part or all of the commission, regardless of whether the customer is assigned to him or not.

As a takeaway from the exercise, think of the use-case as one of many, many edge cases where the theory and the specs quickly get shredded to pieces by realities on the field, and where being pragmatic and flexible in a DB design trounces sticking to the spec.